# How to go through the same dataset several times on tensorflow with queues

Tags: tensorflow

I have a dataset. In order to train on it, I want to put it through an optimizer several times. How can I do this with a queue mechanism? Are there any standard methods of doing so?

Comment: IMO, the question isn't too broad. The question is how to go over dataset several times with the queue mechanism, and that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queue-based TensorFlow input pipeline typically begins with some kind of "input producer" stage, such as a [`tf.train.string_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer), [`tf.train.slice_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/slice_input_producer), or the generic [`tf.train.input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/input_producer). These input producers each take an optional `num_epochs` argument, and are backed by a "queue runner" thread that repeatedly enqueues the input `num_epochs` times into the input pipeline.

Passing `num_epochs=n` to one of these input producer functions will cause the input pipeline to receive `n` copies of the input data. You can also repeat the input infinitely, by passing `num_epochs=None`.

Comment: I tried doing this but didn't succeed. Could you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598708/queue-created-with-slice-input-producer-is-empty