# Queue created with slice_input_producer is empty

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

xs = tf.random_normal([5, 2])
ys = xs[:, 0] + xs[:, 1] + tf.random_normal([5], stddev=0.01)

xs_inp, ys_inp = tf.train.slice_input_producer([xs, ys], num_epochs=20)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for i in range(100):
        print(sess.run([xs_inp, ys_inp]))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

It seems to me that I should take 100 pairs and print them but the program doesn't print anything, and throws exception.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer/input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a tricky puzzle: it turns out that you need to add `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())` before you start the queue runners:

```
import tensorflow as tf

xs = tf.random_normal([5, 2])
ys = xs[:, 0] + xs[:, 1] + tf.random_normal([5], stddev=0.01)

xs_inp, ys_inp = tf.train.slice_input_producer((xs, ys), num_epochs=20)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for i in range(100):
        print(sess.run([xs_inp, ys_inp]))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Why is this necessary? When you set `num_epochs=20`, TensorFlow implicitly creates a "local variable" that acts as a counter for the current epoch index; when this counter reaches 20, the queue will be closed. Like all other TensorFlow variables, this counter must be initialized. If you don't initialize it, it appears that queue runners will raise an error immediately (without printing it, sadly) and close the queue... giving the error that you were seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are so helpful. It would take me a couple of days to find out what's wrong without you.